# EhCache Spring XML integration namespace

Tags: java, xml, spring, ehcache

I'd like to use EhCache with Spring. I've followed a [tutorial](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/spring-caching-with-ehcache/) which said to add this line to my spring.xml:

```
<ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" />
```

The problem is that the ehcache namespace is not present in the tutorial. Looking on Google I've found out the following spring configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">
```

But I get an error about the xsd schema not found and actually if I follow the xsd URL I get a 404.

So the question is, where do I find the namespace and schema?

For the sake of clarity, here's the errors I get on the annotation-driven line:

- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'ehcache:annotation-driven'.
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd', because 1) could not find the 
   document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use:

```
<beans ...
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        ...
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
```

and

```
<cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager" />
```

Then the specific binding to ehcache is in the cacheManager bean

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" ... />
```

Comment: That was it, thank you! No clue why it was so difficult to found... I guess the project has been inglobated altogether within Spring...

Comment: Do we have to add any dependency for this spring-cache ?

Comment: @HardRocker - [spring-context-support](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:spring-context-support)